# Issues with simple jQuery Visibility toggle

Tags: jquery, html, visibility

Can't figure out why this isn't working...

HTML

```
<button id="new_user">+ Create a New User</button>
<div id="create_user" style="visibility:hidden">Test</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#new_user').click(function(){
  if ($('#create_user').css('visibility') == "hidden"){
      $('#create_user').css("visibility","visible");
  } else {
      $('#create_user').css("visibility","hidden");
  }
});
```

Comment: Pen of your code to play with http://codepen.io/anthonyastige/pen/mERYRd

Comment: What is not working? For me, it works! https://jsfiddle.net/t9nxrrbj/

Comment: Your code works fine. Check the console for errors. Also note that you can make this *much* simpler by just calling `$('#create_user').toggle();`

Comment: Something has to be different. I have it in my own tab of jsfiddle and it's not working. :/

Comment: @Nicole have you included jQuery?

Comment: @billyonecan - Yes, I have. :)

Comment: @Nicole show me your fiddle!

Comment: If you know how to check console log, see if there's any error message. For most browsers pressing F12 will do the work.

Comment: Moved all the scripts down to the bottom of the code and it works now. Still not sure why it wasn't working in jsfiddle but I accidentally closed it. Thanks guys.

Comment: You didn't put your code in a ready state then. Put `$(function() { /* your code */ })` around your stuff and it work's even written above. :) Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/t9nxrrbj/1/ or see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working generally fine. https://jsfiddle.net/t9nxrrbj/
But I would prefer `show`, `hide` or maybe just `toggle`:

```
$('#new_user').click(function() {
    $('#create_user').toggle();
});
```

or

```
$('#new_user').click(function() {
    if( !$('#create_user').is(':visible') ) {
        $('#create_user').show();
    } else {
        $('#create_user').hide();
    }
});
```

And put your code in a ready state callback from jQuery. This helps, bacuse it wait with the binding of `click` ro your element until the DOM is ready.
https://jsfiddle.net/t9nxrrbj/1/

```
$(function() {
    $('#new_user').click(function() {
        $('#create_user').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without checking for the visibility, you can simply use toggle()

```
<button id="new_user">+ Create a New User</button>
<div id="create_user" style="display:none">Test</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new_user').click(function() {
    $('#create_user').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#new_user').click(function(){
      $('#create_user').toggleClass("hide show");//toggel class to hide or show
});
```

```css
.hide{visibility:hidden}
.show{visibility:visible}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="new_user">+ Create a New User</button>
<div id="create_user" class='hide'>Test</div>
```

1. Have a class hide and show, hide the div on load
2. On button click use `.toggleClass()` to toggle hide and show